# Idea vs Eclipce или другая?

Tags: java, ide

Какую IDE вы используете при разработке java-приложений? Какие плюсы/минусы есть у различных вариантов. Так же интересует возможность разрабатывать приложения под мобильные платформы, например, android.

Answer (score 3):

Обычно Eclipse. Конечно у неё есть свои недостатки. К примеру её надо настраивать: надо доставлять необходимый функционал, делать свои настройки под шрифты, которые не идеальны, всё это требует времени. Idea в эргономичном плане более продумана, но она платна, да и популярностью больше пользуется eclipse, который при должной настройке не будет ей уступать. Я склонился к eclipse т.к. он более opensource и free, а также более популярен, что зачастую означает меньшее время на разруливание проблем. Что же касается Android, то как и практически любой другой вопрос подобного плана для eclipse решается установкой [плагина](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/eclipse-adt.html). Если верить JetBrains, то и [там](http://blogs.jetbrains.com/idea/tag/android/) проблем тоже нет

Comment: При использовании плагинов для Eclipse можно настроить сборщик C/C++ и писать смещанное приложение на Java/C/C++ из одной среды. Правда отладчик C/C++ все равно будет нужен внешний.

Comment: Безусловно! Более того, помимо c/c++ также можно настроить php/perl/ruby и многое другое. Я так себе TeX настраивал и верстал из Eclipse, кроме того есть плагин SQLExplorer (http://www.sqlexplorer.org/), который играет роль клиента к практически любой бд (дайте только драйвер)
P.S.: кто-нибудь знает, как в комментах линки делать? подскажите плз, если это возможно

Comment: Сейчас разметка в комментариях отключена, поэтому ссылки не ввести. Вы полагаете, что ее стоит включить?

Comment: Когда-то я писал большое С++ приложение с пользовательским интерфейсом на java. Я использовал Visual Studio и для java и для С++.
PS: Разметка в комментариях - здравая мысль.

Comment: А почему никто не упоминает NetBeans? Замечательная вещь, я пользуюсь только им. Удобные предустановки - после инсталляции ничего не меняю, кроме рабочей папки. Удобная установка плагинов - я сейчас NetBeans использую для Java, C/C++, php, PERL и даже html и css.. :)

Answer (score 3):

IDEA коммерческий продукт, а это само по себе означает, что продукт более высокого качества, поскольку его нужно продать клиентам при наличии на рынке бесплатных IDE, как Eclipse.
С другой стороны у Eclipse огромная поддержка о стороны производителей разных продуктов, например Google выпустило свой **официальный** плагин для App Engine и GWT только для Eclipse. Также, если посмотрите в интернете чаще всего плагины официальные плагины написаны именно для Eclipse. Но нельзя сказать, что на IDEA этих плагинов нет.
Я бы рекомендовал Eclipse, поскольку у него самое большое, на мой взгляд, сообщество, а это значит, что в сети очень много примеров, исходников, плагинов и т.д.

Answer (score 1):

Если под андроид, то eclipse или idea. Сам не программировал под андроид, но читал, что есть расширения под него. Сам пользуюсь netBeans, привык: довольно простой, много примеров прямо на сайте; поюзал eclipse: субъективно мне менее удобно, хотя + есть нормальные русские меню, если понимаешь то, что хочешь делать, то легко разобраться.

Answer (score 0):

IDEA продумано так, переходить на него из другой среды легко (можно использовать keymap от многих IDE: VS, Eclipse, JBuilder и т.д). Подсказки и применение шорт-киев дает экономию много времени. После программировании на C# в среде VS, перешел в IDEA для написания Android приложении. Отладчик, декомпилятор Java очень удобны.